# how to Activate QLineEdit when QCheckBox pyqt5 qt designer is checked?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I just started learning pyqt5 qt designer. I used to use tkinter. I have a problem, and I can't figure out how to do it. As the picture shows, there are QCheckBox and QLineEdit. Keep the LineEdit field 'disabled' when checkbox is not checked; When the CheckBox is checked, I try to get the LineEdit field to be activated in the 'normal' position.

[image]

[image]

when i use tkinter,

```
txtSample.configure(state=DISABLED)

txtSample = Checkbutton( text='TEST', variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0,font('arial',16,'bold'))

txtSample = Entry(font=('arial',16,'bold'), bd=8, width=6, justify='left',state=DISABLED)

def checkbuttonSample():
    if(var.get() == 1):
        txtSample.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var.get()== 0:
        txtSample.configure(state=DISABLED)`
```

I would use similar code like this.But I couldn't find a solution and I am looking for a solution about this issue. Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code it's pretty simple: you need to connect the [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal of the checkbox to the [`setEnabled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) slot of the line edit:

```
self.lineEdit.setEnabled(False)
self.checkBox.toggled.connect(self.lineEdit.setEnabled)
```

You can also do it directly in Designer:

- select the line edit;
- on the Property Editor panel, uncheck the "Enabled" option;
- enter the "Edit Signals/Slots" mode (from the tool bar or the "Edit" menu);
- press the left mouse button on the checkbox, move the mouse on the line edit, then release the button;
- in the "Configure Connection" dialog that will be opened afterwards, select the "toggled(bool)" signal on the left, check the "Show signals and slots inherited from QWidget" option, and select "setEnabled(bool)" slot, then click "Ok";